# How to fix the Datepicker in sharepoint Client object?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

```js
 //Date Picker Object
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var myCounter = 1;
            $(".myDate").datepicker();



            $(".myDate").on('focus', function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                if (!$this.data('datepicker')) {
                    $this.removeClass("hasDatepicker");
                    $this.datepicker();
                    $this.datepicker("show");
                }
            });


        });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />


 <input class="myDate" type="text" name="inputDate1" size="autofill" placeholder="Select End Date"
                        style="margin-right: 20px; text-align: right" readonly /></input>
```

I have a problem to fix the datepicker js file into sharepoint. I tried datepicker() function but it shows "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function".

But actually i got ans without sharepoint content. I required the flow which works in sharepoint. Can you please suggest me how to rectify the issue.

Thanks in Advance...

//Date Picker Object
        $(document).ready(function () {

```
        var myCounter = 1;
        $(".myDate").datepicker();



        $(".myDate").on('focus', function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (!$this.data('datepicker')) {
                $this.removeClass("hasDatepicker");
                $this.datepicker();
                $this.datepicker("show");
            }
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure  why you add focus function for datepicker.

Below script works fine in my local.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />


    <input class="myDate" type="text" name="inputDate1" size="autofill" placeholder="Select End Date"
           style="margin-right: 20px; text-align: right" readonly />


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var myCounter = 1;
            $(".myDate").datepicker();
            //$(".myDate").on('focus', function () {
            //    var $this = $(this);
            //    if (!$this.data('datepicker')) {
            //        $this.removeClass("hasDatepicker");
            //        $this.datepicker();
            //        $this.datepicker("show");
            //    }
            //});
        });
    </script>
```

[image]

For troubleshooting.

Use developer tool to check the libraries loaded successfully.

If the libraries not loaded successfully, download and save to SharePoint and load form SharePoint.

for example:

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

[image]